# How can I stop if the number is <= 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to stop my program when the Warrior are Priest are both with 0 or < 0 or the vampire goes to 0 our < 0 if not they will not advance for the next round and just finish the battle that way, and set up a winner.

```
while (warrior[0] and priest[0]) > 0 or vampire[0] > 0: #Loop until all of the group die or the enemy dies
        first_turn() #Execute the first turn
        if (warrior[0] and priest[0]) > 0 or vampire[0] > 0:
            second_turn() #Execute the second turn
        if (warrior[0] and priest[0]) > 0 or vampire[0] > 0:
            third_turn() #Execute the third turn
        if (warrior[0] and priest[0]) > 0 or vampire[0] > 0:
            initiative_phase()
        else:
            break
```

I've tried the way it is above, but I'm not catching why is it not stopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the while condition to:

```
 while (warrior[0] > 0 or priest[0] > 0) and vampire[0] > 0:
```

We added parenthesis Because precedence of logical 'and' is greater than the logical 'or'.
If warrior[0]>0 is true it does not consider whether vampire[0]>0 condition at all.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you need parentheses.

```
while ((warrior[0] > 0 or priest[0] > 0) and vampire[0] > 0): #Loop until all of the group die or the enemy dies
    execute_turn() #Execute the turn
else:  #someone died
     break
```